# Object detection use yolo_v3

Tags: computer-vision, google-colaboratory, object-detection, darknet

```
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_training.cfg darknet53.conv.74 -dont_show
#!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_training.cfg /mydrive/data/yolov3_training_last.weights -dont_show
```

> /bin/bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory

This the last step for training my dataset, but it does not work